# Magento admin dashboard issue graph is working but revenue, shipping, order is zero

Tags: statistics, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, dashboard

Magento admin dashboard graph is working all periods but last 24 hours, last 7 days, Current month is Revenue, tax, Shipping Zero and same as for total amount tab. Please see the screenshot. Issue is Summary is Zero.

**Screenshot :**

[image]

Comment: I have added screenshot

Answer (score 1):

This is a very easy fix, if your dashboard graphs that show the number of orders and the turnover aren’t working all you need to do it to go to the following location:

```
 \app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\dashboard\graph.phtml
```

Then find this code:

```
<img src="getChartUrl(false) ?>" alt="chart" title="chart" />
```

Modify it to the following code:

```
<img src="getChartUrl(true) ?>" alt="chart" title="chart" />
```

Refresh your cache and this work